# Is is possible to target last element inside a class div? CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I understand that I can target the last element if they are using the same class or they are the same element. But the way I am building is user will put in whatever element inside the  (please see attached example). Just wondering is it still possible to call out by CSS? or that will be something cannot be done by CSS?

```css
.header p:last-of-type{
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>I am numbe one</h1>
  <h3>number two</h3>
  <p>something</p>
  <p>something</p>
  <button>last one - red</button>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <h1>I am numbe one</h1>
  <h3>number two</h3>
  <p>last one - red</p>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <p>number 1</p>
  <h1>something</h1>
  <h3>last one - red</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `.header *:last-child`

Comment: cool! you helped with my question! thank you

Comment: Note that if you only want to target a direct child, you need `.header > *:last-child` (and as an aside, you can use `<header>` instead of `<div class="header">`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes with `last-child` and `.header p:last-child` will target the last child if it's `<p> </p>` element and if you want to target the last element in a div that have a `.header` as a class.

you can use `.header *:last-child` as mention in the comments section by [@Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207022/is-is-possible-to-target-last-element-inside-a-class-div-css/58207123#comment102792102_58207022)

```css
.header *:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>I am numbe one</h1>
  <h3>number two</h3>
  <p>something</p>
  <p>something</p>
  <button>last one - red</button>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <h1>I am numbe one</h1>
  <h3>number two</h3>
  <p>last one - red</p>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <p>number 1</p>
  <h1>something</h1>
  <h3>last one - red</h3>
  <p>ddd</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to just add `color: red;` styling to the last `<p>` tag inside the last `class='header'` class, then you should use 
**[CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**:

**CSS:**

```
.header:last-of-type p:last-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

You can check this **[working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/27mn6Lw5/1/)**.

**Edit:**

If you want to target the last element of each tag with the `class='header'`, you coud accomplish it like so:

**CSS:**

```
.header *:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Check the **[working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mr4ok0jz/)**.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.header *:last-child{
color : red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<h1>I am numbe one</h1>
<h3>number two</h3>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<button>last one - red</button>
</div>

<div class="header">
<h1>I am numbe one</h1>
<h3>number two</h3>
<p>last one - red</p>
</div>

<div class="header">
<p>number 1</p>
<h1>something</h1>
<h3>last one - red</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of an earlier answer, just with less explanatory text